# Как исправить семантическую ошибку вложенной формы поиска в списке?

Tags: html, css, поиск, форма

Есть блок с формой поиска, который работает исправно, но имеет ошибку валидации

> Error: Unclosed element form.

Код:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.search-box {
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

ul.cols {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box ul.cols li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul.cols>li {
  display: table-cell;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-box ul.cols li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
}

.search-box form {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 250px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)!important;
  margin: 0px;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  background: #363636;
  font-family: "gothampro-light", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.search-box a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.search-box a svg {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-box" class="search-box">
  <ul class="cols">

    <li>

      <form id="frm_search_top" action="{$search_url}" method="get">

        <input type="text" id="search_top" name="search" />

    </li>

    <li>

      <a href="#search" onclick="$('#frm_search_top').submit();"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M19.5,17.2c0,0-4.3-4.3-4.4-4.4c0.9-1.3,1.4-2.8,1.4-4.5c0-4.5-3.7-8.2-8.2-8.2S0,3.7,0,8.2s3.7,8.2,8.2,8.2c1.7,0,3.2-0.5,4.5-1.4l4.4,4.4c0.7,0.7,1.7,0.7,2.4,0C20.2,19,20.2,17.9,19.5,17.2zM8.2,13.7c-3,0-5.4-2.4-5.4-5.4s2.4-5.4,5.4-5.4s5.4,2.4,5.4,5.4S11.2,13.7,8.2,13.7z"/></svg></a>

      </form>

    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Если я форму выношу за список `ul`, то получаю искажение фона с иконкой поиска.

Код:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.search-box {
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

ul.cols {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box ul.cols li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul.cols>li {
  display: table-cell;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-box ul.cols li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
}

.search-box form {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 250px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)!important;
  margin: 0px;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  background: #363636;
  font-family: "gothampro-light", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.search-box a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.search-box a svg {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-box" class="search-box">
  <form id="frm_search_top" action="{$search_url}" method="get">
    <ul class="cols">

      <li>

        <input type="text" id="search_top" name="search" />

      </li>

      <li>

        <a href="#search" onclick="$('#frm_search_top').submit();"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M19.5,17.2c0,0-4.3-4.3-4.4-4.4c0.9-1.3,1.4-2.8,1.4-4.5c0-4.5-3.7-8.2-8.2-8.2S0,3.7,0,8.2s3.7,8.2,8.2,8.2c1.7,0,3.2-0.5,4.5-1.4l4.4,4.4c0.7,0.7,1.7,0.7,2.4,0C20.2,19,20.2,17.9,19.5,17.2zM8.2,13.7c-3,0-5.4-2.4-5.4-5.4s2.4-5.4,5.4-5.4s5.4,2.4,5.4,5.4S11.2,13.7,8.2,13.7z"/></svg></a>


      </li>

    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто закройте форму в первом елементи списка, вам не нужно вкладывать ссылку в форму.

```html
<div id="search-box" class="search-box">
  <ul class="cols">

    <li>

      <form id="frm_search_top" action="{$search_url}" method="get">

        <input type="text" id="search_top" name="search" />
      </form>
      
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#search" onclick="$('#frm_search_top').submit();"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M19.5,17.2c0,0-4.3-4.3-4.4-4.4c0.9-1.3,1.4-2.8,1.4-4.5c0-4.5-3.7-8.2-8.2-8.2S0,3.7,0,8.2s3.7,8.2,8.2,8.2c1.7,0,3.2-0.5,4.5-1.4l4.4,4.4c0.7,0.7,1.7,0.7,2.4,0C20.2,19,20.2,17.9,19.5,17.2zM8.2,13.7c-3,0-5.4-2.4-5.4-5.4s2.4-5.4,5.4-5.4s5.4,2.4,5.4,5.4S11.2,13.7,8.2,13.7z"/></svg></a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```